# How to give ripple effect on touch on a view in ipad application

Tags: xcode, ios4, ios5

I want to use ripple effect on a specific area of view when the touch event happens.
I used the following code:

```
CATransition *animation=[CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setDuration:1.75];
    [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [animation setType:@"rippleEffect"];

    [animation setFillMode:kCAFillModeRemoved];
    animation.endProgress=0.99;        

    [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
    [self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

But this one give effect on whole,but I want the effect on a fixed area where touch event happens.
How to do that???Kindly help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you detect where the touch is, put a transparent UIView on top of it for example 20 pixels around the touch, an add the animation to that only view?

If you need the code I can write to you.